# How to Intent Image from Adapter class to an Activity class fetched from Web Service?

Tags: android

```
if(!imglist.containsKey(temp.getString("event_image_thumb"))) {

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.loadImage(temp.getString("event_image_thumb"), new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    imglist.put(imageUri, loadedImage);
                    messageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }

            });
else
        {

            holder.thum1.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.thum2.setImageBitmap(null);

            holder.thum1.setImageBitmap(imglist.get(temp.getString("event_image_thumb")));
            holder.thum2.setImageBitmap(imglist.get(temp.getString("event_image_thumb")));
        }



        final int position = grid.getPositionForView((View)v.getParent());
  Intent touch =new Intent(context,Touch.class);
  touch.putExtra("data",getItem(position));
        context.startActivity(touch);
    }
};
```

The problem I am facing is The image is not passed into the activity class

Comment: are u downloading images ?

Comment: I have downloaded the images in adapter class but I  want to show the images from activity class

Comment: in that case, you can pass the image  downloaded path to second activity an load it from there

Comment: You mean that I have to make a class where I will be storing the downloaded images and then call that class from activity.. I am also thinking like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think object that you ar passing by following line has a bitmap
touch.putExtra("data",getItem(position));

passing a bitmap can harm the app. possibly it can be big and can have outofmemmory error

So if your object do have bitmap inside than  i sugest dont do that 
Solution is 
 1. cache your image in your internal or external storage 
    if you dont want any one to see this image than store it in internal with MODE_PRIVATE 
 2. send image uri in your extras only 
 3. access this uri from your second activity and get this image from that uri and show in second activity